# ORA-12154 when PLSQL Developer 11 is trying to connect to database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

Hi i have troubles when i'm trying to connect my PLSQL Developer to Oracle 11g R2 Express Edition.

I created a new folder in c:\Oraclex86, in that folder I  installed the oracle 11g R2 Client for x86

I have installed the PLSQL Developer in c:\ProgramFiles cause I read in others publications, that c:\ProgramFiles(x86) generate connections issues.

So when I try to connect the PLSQL Developer to the database the ORA-12154 message appears

As additional information I have checked this things:

Oracle Services is already running

PLSQL Developer Preferences:
[PLSQL Developer Preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vn4vy.jpg)

ORACLE 11g R2 Login[11g R2 Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cKs8.jpg)

I have Windows 10 x64 Edition

Tnsnames configuration:

```
XE =   (DESCRIPTION =
       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Adriano_PC)(PORT = 1521))
       (CONNECT_DATA =
         (SERVER = DEDICATED)
         (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
       )   )

   EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =   (DESCRIPTION =
       (ADDRESS_LIST =
         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
       )
       (CONNECT_DATA =
         (SID = PLSExtProc)
         (PRESENTATION = RO)
       )   )

   ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =    (DESCRIPTION = 
       (ADDRESS_LIST = 
         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
       ) 
       (CONNECT_DATA = 
         (SID = CLRExtProc) 
         (PRESENTATION = RO) 
       )    )
```

Listener:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =   (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )   )

LISTENER =   (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Adriano_PC)(PORT = 1521))
    )   )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

SQLNET:

```
This file is actually generated by netca. But if customers choose to 
install "Software Only", this file wont exist and without the native 
authentication, they will not be able to connect to the database on NT.

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)
```

That's anyone knows what I'm doing wrong? It I'll appreciate your help

Comment: You said that installed oracle on `c:\Oraclex86` but your listener configuration is pointing to `C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server` maybe it is your problem ?

Comment: Hi Jorge thanks for your comment, i have installed the oracle client x86 into ORACLEx86 folder but the the database are in C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server , that's ok right?, What line should I change, in the listener?

Comment: That's was just a though. I've never used oracle xe myself. Try to run in the console tnslistener yourServiceID and see what happens

Comment: Using tnsping to XE and host (computer name) the result was OK, any other suggestion?

Comment: Can you connect use SQL*Plus?

Comment: This question would probably be better on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ok, i'll post it in dba.stackechange.com thanks!